# Htaccess 301 redirect one url to another with special characters doesnt work

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

I need to 301 redirect one URL to another. Now I have this rule in `.htaccess`

`RewriteRule /forum/viewtopic.php?f=65&t=6 /page/name-of-the-page [R=301]`

`RewriteRule /forum/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=5 /page/another-name-of-the-page [R=301]`

But it doesnt work at all. Could please anybody help me with that?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Have you been able to get other RewriteRules to successfully fire? You should consider configuring RewriteLog for debugging purposes (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog)

Comment: Yes, i have more rules and everything works, but these simple lines dont. I suppose, problem is with ?f=65&t=6 etc. because simple RewriteRule /forum/ /page/name-of-the-page [R=301] works :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant match query string using `RewriteRule`. Use it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^f=65&t=6$
RewriteRule ^forum/viewtopic\.php$ /page/name-of-the-page? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^f=30&t=5$
RewriteRule ^forum/viewtopic\.php$ /page/another-name-of-the-page? [R=301,L]
```

`?` in the end is used to strip-off any existing query string.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it doesnt work, but I'll try to work with that and maybe I'll find out

Comment: Just make sure these are first 2 rules in your .htaccess and also make sure that there is no .htaccess in `/forum/` folder.

Comment: Ha, it works! I tried it with / instead of ^ before forum/viewtopic\.php$, so I have /forum/viewtopic\.php$ and it works like a charm. Thank you a lot!

Comment: btw what is that ^ supposed to do?

Comment: `^` in regex means start of input.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule /forum/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=5 /page/another-name-of-the-page [R=301]
RewriteRule /forum/viewtopic.php?f=65&t=6 /page/name-of-the-page [R=301]
```

just reverse the order and it should work!